# memory leaks NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, nsdata

Memory leaks occurred in following lines

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];

NSData *ndata =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:ndata];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the line

```
UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:ndata];
```

Isn't being cleaned up properly. Change this to either:

```
UIImage *image1 = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:ndata] autorelease];
```

or

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:ndata];
```

Your imageURL (`NSURL`) and ndata (`NSData`) are autoreleased so this should clean up your errors.

Answer (score -4):

U can release the locally created objects at the end of the function like below

```
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];
  NSData *ndata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:ndata];
  [ndata release];
  [imageURL release];
```

so that the object every time allocated is release in that scope itself

Comment: you are releasing autoreleased object ndata, you will crash

Comment: `NSData` and `NSURL` are both autoreleased in this example, no need to clean up either as both will cause crashes. `UIImage` however should be released.